# How can I add IP Based login in magento admin.

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I want to add IP based Magento admin login. I have tried below code:

```
# Restrict admin access

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=your ip
```

Comment: put the code under RewriteEngine on

Comment: This code is already used in .htaccess, where should I put your code: 

 RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]